# How I gained Reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

[image]

What do this mean? **User was removed**? And I gained $+12$ Repo due to this.

Comment: @WillieWong Don't we get reputation change for meta question?

Comment: Aah! the same happened on physics.SE , I think some one taking a revenge for something is removed.

Comment: Wow.  Somebody must have downvoted the crap out of you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Someone downvoted you, and now the votes were reversed.

Comment: Can I see which questions/answers were downvoted?

Comment: @exploringnet: no. Votes are always kept secret. Sometimes you can infer from other evidence, but you can never find out.

Comment: @exploringnet: No, unless you kept track of the score of each post, in which case you just have to compare before and after.

Comment: @exploringnet: You can see which posts were downvoted (in a global sense and related to a specific downvoter) by going to the "reputation" tab in your user profile and see which posts have -2 and a "downvote" event next to them.  If you don't have too many downvoted posts you should be able to guess which ones were affected by the user removal. The (user)names of downvoters is kept confidential.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I found that it was someone pre planed to do so, via your method I see that it was my questions(only and not answers) were downvoted and as soon as i clich on them to reach the questions , the vote count in questions seems to be increased!
 `:)`